# duplicate cache pages: Varnish

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish, drupal

Recently we have configured Varnish on our server, it was successfully setup but we noticed that if we open any page in multiple browsers, the Varnish send request to Apache not matter page is cached or not. If we refresh twice on each browser it creates duplicate copies of the same page.

**What exactly should happen:**

If any page is cached by Varnish, the subsequent request should be served from Varnish itself when we are opening the same page in browser OR we are opening that page from different IP address.

**Following is my default.vcl file**

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if( req.url ~ "^/search/.*$")
    {
    }else {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*", "");
}

if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
}

if (!req.backend.healthy) {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

set req.grace = 6h;

if (req.url ~ "^/status\.php$" ||
        req.url ~ "^/update\.php$" ||
        req.url ~ "^/admin$" ||
        req.url ~ "^/admin/.*$" ||
        req.url ~ "^/flag/.*$" ||
        req.url ~ "^.*/ajax/.*$" ||
        req.url ~ "^.*/ahah/.*$") {
            return (pass);
}

if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(pdf|asc|dat|txt|doc|xls|ppt|tgz|csv|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

if (req.http.Cookie) {
    set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");    
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(SESS[a-z0-9]+|SSESS[a-z0-9]+|NO_CACHE)=", "; \1=");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

        if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
            unset req.http.Cookie;
        }
        else {
            return (pass);
        }
}

if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD" &&
    req.request != "PUT" && req.request != "POST" &&
    req.request != "TRACE" && req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
    req.request != "DELETE") 
    {return(pipe);}     /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */

if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
    return (pass);
}

if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
        # No point in compressing these
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
        # unknown algorithm
        remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
}
    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT";
    }
    else {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    if (beresp.status == 404 || beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 500) {
        set beresp.ttl = 10m;
}
if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(pdf|asc|dat|txt|doc|xls|ppt|tgz|csv|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
    set beresp.grace = 6h;
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    set req.http.connection = "close";
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") 
        {ban_url(req.url);
    error 200 "Purged";}

    if (!obj.ttl > 0s)
        {return(pass);}
}

sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") 
        {error 200 "Not in cache";}
}
```

**Solution**

**Pitfall - Vary: User-Agent**

Some applications or application servers send Vary: User-Agent along with their content. This instructs Varnish to cache a separate copy for every variation of User-Agent there is. There are plenty. Even a single patchlevel of the same browser will generate at least 10 different User-Agent headers based just on what operating system they are running.

So if you really need to Vary based on User-Agent be sure to normalize the header or your hit rate will suffer badly. Use the above code as a template.

https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/vary.html#tutorial-vary

**Workaround**

One workaround, is to do what we call "User-Agent-Washing", where
Varnish rewrites the Useragent to the handfull of different variants
your backend really cares about, along the lines of:

```
sub vcl_recv {
       if (req.http.user-agent ~ "MSIE") {
           set req.http.user-agent = "MSIE";
   } else {
           set req.http.user-agent = "Mozilla";
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you come to know that varnish created duplicate copies of the page ?

Also, is your site public and can we also take a look at that. If so, please paste me the URL.

Comment: @GeekRide, yes sure http://www.nutritionrank.com is the site. I opened two different browser (Chrome, Safari). With Chrome I opened a one url http://www.nutritionrank.com/brands. On the very first time Cache was MISS, so I refreshed the page again and second time it was HIT. Now after this I went to Safari browser and opened the same url. Unfortunately first time again it was MISS and on second time it was HIT. It leads to me that Varnish is caching single page multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that it's impossible for varnish to cache 2 copies of a URL.

Now, I am not sure about the Hit/Miss check, but when I need to check, I will do that in the firefox and use Firebug for that.

I will open the firebug and open the website.

In that, it will show the age of the every page/image fetched, like shown in the picture attached.

If age is increasing by time, then for me Varnish is working pretty well.

And what I can see, it's working fine for your site too.

[image: How to check Varnish Cache working]

Comment: #GeekRide, Firstly thanks for looking at the issue. I agree with what you said, but why there is redudancy in Age & X-Varnish tags, please see here http://i.imgur.com/NG6wh.png

Comment: I believe the two sections are from the different browsers but the same URL or is it something else ?

Comment: left is from console with different IP Address and right is from Chrome browser with different IP Address

Comment: Ok. I might have figured the issue. So, I don't see anywhere in your VCL for the redirection of non-www URLs to www and neither vice versa. So, If someone opens some URL with www and someone opens the same URL with non-www, then the varnish will cache both the pages differently. To avoid this, you can put this line in Varnish's vcl_recv sub.

`set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "^www\.example\.com$","example.com");`

After putting this into vcl file, just restart/reload varnish and do the test again.

Hopefully this will fix the issue.

Comment: I am doing it via .htaccess from non-www to www redirect, but I will add you option. Secondly the issue is not with url as I type same url on different IP addresses and get first time MISS and Second time HIT. Moreover the Age tag as different values on different ip addresses (I did this via console).

Comment: Though a vague question, but which version of Varnish you are using ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6742/discussion-between-geekride-and-sukhjinder-singh)

Comment: Also, Is there any specific reason you ar using vcl_hash function or you just enabled it ? If not, then can you please try commenting that and then testing the Varnish caching.

Comment: Also, once you have tested the last and kind of most important thing I could think of is put this line before the closing brackets of vcl_fetch subroutine.
`return(deliver);`
Reason is **When deliver is encountered it tells Varnish that the object it currently is working with should be inserted into the cache.**

Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: I apologies for late reply, I will implement and reply back to you with the output.

Comment: I am using Varnish Cache 3.0.2

Comment: Commented out vcl_hash & Added return(deliver); to vcl_fetch but still not working.

Comment: Wow ... not I can't really think of anything. Still I will keep digging and will let you know in case I found anything at all.

Comment: Thanks GeekRide, please keeps us posted incase you find some solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is what helped me solve this problem:

<strike>Uncomment</strike> Comment out or delete the lines that form your `vch_hash` function and restart varnish. `vcl_hash` is used to create specific caches, say for a user or a session or a certain IP address. If you want the page to be served from (after it has been cached) cache, you can do away with the vcl_hash function.

Test it out in a test environment first, just in case.

HTH.

**Edit (Clarification)**

**Option 1**:

Comment out these lines by adding "#" sign at the beginning of each line. So these lines

```
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (hash);
}
```

would become:

```
#sub vcl_hash {
#    hash_data(req.url);
#    if (req.http.host) {
#        hash_data(req.http.host);
#    } else {
#        hash_data(server.ip);
#    }
#    return (hash);
#}
```

Lines beginning with a  `#` are ignored by varnish.

**Option 2**:

Alternatively, you can remove the above lines all together. The end result is the same.

Comment: if you check my default.vcl, it is already enabled.

Comment: Uncomment = disable (-: Uncomment the lines that form the `vcl_hash` function, and see what you get.

Comment: I sincerely regret if I am not able understand what you said. You mean I should remove following lines or something else?<br />
`sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
      hash_data(req.http.host);
     } else {
      hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (hash);
  }`

Comment: The regret and error is mine. You understood "uncomment" correctly. I've updated my answer, and hope that helps clear up things. In short, those lines can be removed either by commenting them out or deleting them all together.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if this works as well. Same is advised by @GeekRide as well.

Comment: Why the down vote?